# Transfer calendar events ownership via Google Calendar API. cURL JSON

Tags: curl, events, google-calendar-api, transfer, ownership

Has anyone managed to programmatically create and send the "change ownership request" email to the specified new owner?

Assuming:

- OAuth finely works as spected in any other request.
- Calendar and Event IDs are correctly set.
- The only detail from new owner is the mail adderess. (Not in the organization btw.).
- The new owner is on attendees.

I've been dealing with PATCH, UPDATE, MOVE... but can't find the right way. Not even any code to mess with!!

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey there, so you would like to change the owner of an event? Or the owner of the whole calendar? Can you be more precise please? @Confuziacul